# Disabled ComboBox data-bound SelectedItem property is being set on double-click

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, combobox

In a `DataGrid` I have a `ComboBox` as a field type. When I disable this `ComboBox` for a particular row via `IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabledState}"` the control is disabled.

But when I double-click the control then the property's setter is invoked which somehow causes the `ComboBox` to go empty (even though the setter property is assigning the proper visible selected value).

Has anybody else seen this quircky behavior as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** Closed ***

It turns out the ComboBox inside my DataGrid wasnt the problem. It was the DataGrid. Setting the grid to readonly solved the problem (i.e double-clicking on a DataGrid cell will cause the cell to enter EditMode, by default). This edit mode was causing the issue described for the ComboBox!